# Keep the focus to the current row while adding new rows dynamically to the jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, treeview

I have jqgrid-treegrid in a system to display all records in the same page with scrolls. But Im loading the records dynamically after loading set of records initially(kind of backgroud process).

One of the grid column is editable, so I keep update that particular cell in each row as the rest of the rows are being added to the grid.

The problem is as Im using

```
afterInsertRow: function(id)
{
  jQuery('#myGrid').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
}
```

to set the row editable, Im losing the focus(cursor) from the current row to the newly added row.

But I really need to keep the cursor to the current row without interrupting my updating process.

Help me on this pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way...

I commented this line in *jquery.jqGrid.src.js* (line no 9035)

```
//$("td:eq("+focus+") input",ind).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this API

```
$(grid).setSelection(selectedGuidRow, true);
```

For more detail [JqGris.Selection](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/selection/selectedrow_client/default.php)

Comment: Thank you for answering, But my problem is not with the row selection. The selection remains with the current row but the cursor only moves to the input field of the newly added row. Hope you got this issue.